# ElasticSearch NEST UpdateDescriptor scriptId does not work, gives System.MissingMethodException

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

The newly added "ScriptId" for the UpdateDescriptor does not seem to work. At runtime I get the following error:

System.MissingMethodException was unhandled
  HResult=-2146233069
  Message=Method not found: 'Nest.UpdateDescriptor`2 Nest.UpdateDescriptor`2.ScriptId(System.String)'.
  Source=SMSProcessManagers
  StackTrace:
       at TestApp.TestApplication.Program.Main(String[] args) in e:\src\Applications\TestApplication\Program.cs:line 49
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:

Does anyone know what is the fix for this?

Comment: I had an issue with the copy & Paste. The error I received is:
Nest.UpdateDescriptor`2<!0,!1> Nest.UpdateDescriptor`2.ScriptId(System.String)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue turned out to be an older version of the nest library still present and conflicting with the new version. After uninstalling all nest (and related nuget packages), and re-installing the latest nest package, it worked fine.